The symbol of de Rham cohomology on Stacks Project
In the chapter of de Rham cohomology on Stack Project, there is a symbol $H^{i}(R\Gamma(X, \Omega_{X / S}^{\bullet}))$. What does $R\Gamma$ mean?

Looks like the right-derived functor of the left-exact functor $\Gamma$. (There's a fairly straightforward explanation of this construction in Hartshorne, at least for modules; I don't know what category it stays in.)

If $A = \Gamma(X, \mathscr{O}_X)$, then $R\Gamma(X,\cdot) : D(X) \to D(A)$ is the right derived functor of the global sections functor $\Gamma(X,\cdot) : (\mathscr{O}_X-\text{Mod}) \to (A-\text{Mod})$; it is a (triangulated) functor from the derived category $D(X)$ of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules to the derived category $D(A)$ of $A$-modules.
If $p : X \to S$ is a morphism of schemes, the complex $R\Gamma(X, \Omega_{X/S}^{\,•})$ is an object of $D(\Gamma(S, \mathscr{O}_S))$, so $H^i_{dR}(X/S) = H^i(R\Gamma(X, \Omega_{X/S}^{\, •}))$ is a $\Gamma(S, \mathscr{O}_S)$-module.
